# Controllers for slideshow not inserting correctly using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, append, slideshow, prepend

I'm trying to insert my right and left controllers into the sides of my slideshow div using .prepend() and .append() but instead they display in the top corners of the window

Javascript DOM insert (Running in the .html file):

```
$('#slideShow')
.prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
.append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');
```

Slideshow HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="slice">
<div class="container">
<div id ="mainContent">


  <div id="pageContainer">

 <!-- Slideshow HTML -->
  <div id="slideShow">

    <div id="slidesContainer">

      <div class="slide">

        <h2>Web Development With PHP</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="newphp.JPG" alt="Screen capture of PHP built website" width="215" height="145" /></a></p>

      </div>

      <div class="slide">

        <h2>Database Design with MySQL Workbench</h2>
        <p><a href="file:///C:/Users/Owner/Documents/IRWireframe/experience.html#test"><img src="Patient_Database_Snapshot.JPG" width="215" height="145" alt="MySQL Workbench Database Design Snapshot" /></a></p>

      </div>

      <div class="slide">

        <h2>Web Design With CSS and HTML</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="webdesign.JPG" width="215" height="145" alt="Screen capture of CSS webpage" /></a></p>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
  <!-- Slideshow HTML -->

  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#slideShow {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:640px;
    height:263px;
    background:transparent url(bg_slideshow.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
#slideShow #slidesContainer {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:560px;
  height:263px;
  overflow:auto; /* allow scrollbar */
  position:relative;
}
#slideShow #slidesContainer .slide {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:540px; /* reduce by 20 pixels of #slidesContainer to avoid horizontal scroll */
  height:263px;
}

.control {
  display:block;
  width:39px;
  height:263px;
  text-indent:-10000px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#leftControl {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background:transparent url(control_left.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#rightControl {
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 background:transparent url(control_right.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got position:absolute; on your .control class so the top:0 left:0 and top:0 right:0 properties on #leftControl and #rightControl are positioning based on the entire screen.

Try just floating the controls left and right like

```
#leftControl {
  float:left;
  background:transparent url(control_left.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#rightControl {
 float:right;
 background:transparent url(control_right.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I had actually tried doing that before and the left control appeared where it was supposed to but the right control would display directly under the left controller, rather than on the other end of the div. Would you know a fix for that with just a shot in the dark?

Comment: you'd probably have to float the #slideShow #slidesContainer as well so that it takes up horizontal space between the two.  If you have a URL where I could take a look at it that would be helpful.